# FB.getAccessToken() returns null until after I call FB.getLoginStatus() one time

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm making a very simple Facebook API request. I'm simply running:

```
FB.getAccessToken();
```

... and it's returning null every time. The moment I run:

```
FB.getLoginStatus();
```

... then FB.getAccessToken() *immediately* starts working and returning an access token every time.

There's no code snippets to post because this happens even when I just do it from the JS console (which also means it can't be async issues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FB.getLoginStatus refreshes the Token, so it does make sense that FB.getAccessToken works after calling it. Although there is no use case where this would ever be a problem, you should always use FB.getLoginStatus on page load - and after FB.init, of course.

Btw, i never heard of FB.getAccessToken, and i did not find it in the docs either. This is how you should get the Access Token (if you really need it):

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    }
});
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: Oh, that's perfect. It's possible FB.getAccessToken is deprecated then but it definitely still works. I was mostly looking for a way to avoid making two separate API calls, one after the other, and this does that. Thanks!